# What would be the motto to live a life?according to "GEETA" or any holy book?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, philosophy, life

Whats the main purpose of our life,its not to be just earn money reputation in society and there need to be something else.

If there is any description about that in geeta or any holy book,please help me with that.

and I am not asking "Is the ultimate purpose of life only to serve God?"
I am asking is "What would be ultimate purpose of life?"

Comment: Ramakrishna Paramahamsa said that the message of the Gita could be had by repeating the word 'gita' repeatedly until the vowels reversed into 'tagi' - which means renounce. Renounce the world and seek only God. See Gita XVIII 65-66.

Comment: @keshav,Please remove the duplicate question ,thats not th answer i Want nor the question I have asked.

Comment: @VivekDoshi Obviously any proper answer to the question "Is X the ultimate purpose of life?" would also be a proper answer to the question "What is the ultimate purpose of life?". So I think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan,any way I didn't get the answer from there but thanks for the another question i knew something more.

Comment: Any holy book is fine, including Gita. If you can practice the teachings written down in any holy book, which includes The Bhagavad Gita, Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Satyam Sivam Sundaram, Shankaracharya's Vivekachudamani, Ramana Maharishi's Who Am I, Sai Baba's Shri Sai Satcharita, then you have great change in you and attain happiness eventually. All the best

Answer (score 0):

We all have to live life and we can not escape from it because it is a life cycle where one depends on another and vice-versa. It is quite simple, The Children depend on their parents and further the parents depend on their children. We all here to perform our duty and a part of universal life cycle. If one does not perform his duty or responsibility, there will a disturbance in the life cycle, he will get hatred, loathing and infamy. And if One performs his duty or responsibility very well then he will get reputation, honour, fame and glory and it also affects to his Reincarnation. So the luck of Reincarnation depends on the deeds of the previous birth or current birth too. And this is the base of 'GEETA'.

So In short the purpose of our lives is to perform our duties and responsibilities (Law of Karma). We are the part of life cycle and society and to continue it we all need to live our life.

**If one does not perform his duty or responsibility But what if someone take sanyasa? that will also disturb the life cycle, but taking sanyasa is not also a bad thing right?**

It depends on situations such as If a person is already married and he has one or more children who really rely on the person. In such case A person takes Monasticism (sanyasa) definitely, it will disturb the life cycle. In that case the sanyasa of that person is just like a Suicide. If anyone who wants to do like this then he or she should not get marry. A person should not run away from his/her responsibility.
A person is associated with so may responsibilities towards his parents, wife, children, brothers-sisters.. If A person has performed all his duties or taking sanyasa does not affect anyone in his family then it is worth to take sanyasa for that person.

Comment: If one does not perform his duty or responsibility

But what if someone take sanyas?that will also disturb the life cycle,but taking sanyas is not also a bad thing right?

Comment: my next answer will help you

Comment: I will add it to my answer.Kindly refer my answer again.

Comment: A person is associated with so may responsibilities,such as his parents,wife,children,brothers-sisters.

Person will always be in these bonds,nilkanth(swami narayan) has his family but he left the family in childhood,If you will stay in bond you will never able to take sanyas,am I right?

Comment: Swami Narayan was an avatar of God or a divine self , and God is beyond  all these.He took the sanyas in childhood did not get marry.He was god and took sanyas for particular reasons,that you know very well.

Comment: But he was also bound to the all relation though he has also take the sanyas.was an avatar of God but at last he was in human form the rules are also ment to be applied on him.no?

Comment: He took this decision for the welfare of human beings.So he also performed his duties and responsibilities for by exhorting  human beings to walk on the way of truth.And this was the main reason behind the sanyas of him

Comment: if any person takes sanyas and then he spends his whole life for Human interest and welfare of Human beings then it is the worth reason to take sanyas.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: @keshav ,Thank you for suggestion but dear friend, My answer was based on my reading,knowledge and my point of views.So I have not any web-sources for this particular answer.

Comment: @HardikVyas You don't need to cite web sources; citing physical books is absolutely fine.  But one way or another, answers on this site should be backed up with sources (preferably scripture), because otherwise it's hard for readers to verify if the information in your answer is right or not.  And your answer certainly shouldn't be based on personal opinion.

Comment: @kesav ,Thank you Next Time I will focus on these things